# How can Android app add Easy Stars to a Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Google Maps supports a feature named Easy Stars, whereby users can mark locations so they show with a star on the map when looking at the area.
I would like my Android app to be able to add stars and remove stars from the map like in the Landmarks function in J2ME.
Is there a way to do that?
PS. My app starts Google Maps (or any map program) by using an Android Intent passing a geo location with ?q street and city.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650555

1. type in address
2. touch loction bubble
3. touch grayed out star in top right of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought saddr = Start address and daddr = Destination address, i.e. it has nothing to do with what I asked for, or am I confused?